# I want to pop up a confirmation message after all message after submitting

Tags: javascript, java

This my jsp page and i'm doing Employee management work now and i want to popup a confirmation message after all my validations are successful or true and it should ask user yes or no. for the submission of the form.

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>
<%@ page session="false" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Employee Management System</title>
 <link href="CSS/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

function checkform(pform1){
var str=pform1.bloodGroup.value;
var email = pform1.email.value;
var phone = pform1.phoneNumber.value;
var cleanstr = phone.replace(/[\(\)\.\-\ ]/g, '');
var err={}; 
var validemail =/^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/;
var income = pform1.annualIncome.value;
var Id = pform1.employeeId.value;
var salary = income.replace(/[\(\)\.\-\ ]/g, '');
var Eid = Id.replace(/[\(\)\.\-\ ]/g, '');


//check required fields
//password should be minimum 4 chars but not greater than 8
if (((str.length < 1) || (str.length > 3))&& (!(str.notequals("")))) {

err.message="Invalid blood group"; 
err.field=pform1.bloodGroup; 
}

//validate email
else if( (email != "") && !(validemail.test(email))){
err.message="Invalid email"; 
err.field=pform1.email; 

}

//check phone number
else if (isNaN((cleanstr))) { 
err.message="Invalid phone number"; 
err.field=pform1.phoneNumber; 
}

else if (isNaN((salary))) { 
    err.message="Invalid Annual Income"; 
    err.field=pform1.annualIncome; 
    }


else if (isNaN((Eid))) { 
    err.message="Invalid EmployeeID"; 
    err.field=pform1.annualIncome; 
    }


if(err.message) 
        { 
                document.getElementById('divError').innerHTML = err.message;
                err.field.focus(); 
                alert(err.message);
                return false;        

        } 
else
    {
    return true;
    }



}
</script>


<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#dateOfBirth" ).datepicker({
          showOn: "button",
          buttonImage: "Pictures/calendicon.jpg" ,
          buttonImageOnly: true,
          buttonText: "Select date",
         /*   dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy ' */
        });
  });

</script>


</head>
<body><center>  
<h2>Employee Management System</h2>
<form:form method="POST" action="./add.html" modelAttribute ="employee" onsubmit="return checkform(this);" >
<div id="errmsgbox">

<div id="divError"></div>

</div>



<table  border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="14%">Employee ID<span class="mandatory" >*</span></td>
    <td width="35%"> <form:hidden path="ID" />
    <form:input path="employeeId"  required = "required"/></td>

    <td width="16%">Employee Name<span class="mandatory" >*</span></td>
    <td width="35%"><form:input path="employeeName" required = "required" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>DOB<span class="mandatory" >*</span></td>
    <td><form:input path ="dateOfBirth" required = "required" id="dateOfBirth"></form:input></td>
  <style>
img.ui-datepicker-trigger {
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
}
</style>

    <td>Blood group </td>
    <td><form:input path="bloodGroup" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Annual Income </td>
    <td><form:input path ="annualIncome" /></td> 
    <td>Qualification</td>
    <td><form:input path ="qualification" /></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Pan No.</td>
    <td><form:input path="panNumber" /></td>

    <td>Phone No. </td>
    <td><form:input path="phoneNumber" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Sex</td>
   <td><form:radiobutton path="sex"  value="m"/>Male 
   <form:radiobutton path="sex" value="f"/>Female</td>
    <td>Email</td>
    <td><form:input path="email" /></td>
  </tr>
<tr>
    <td>Address</td>

    <td colspan="3"><textarea name="" cols="" rows="2"></textarea></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div>
     <input name="submit2" type="submit" title="Submit" value="Submit"   />
  <input type="button" name="reset_form" value="Reset" onclick="this.form.reset();"/>
     <a href="index.html"><input name="submit3" type="button" title="Reset" value="View All"/></a>
</div>
</form:form>
</center>


</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace you `else block` by following code in `checkform()`:

```
if(confirm("Your question here?")) {
   return true;
} else {
   return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use alert() in the javascript.